# If $e^{-f}$ is bounded and analytic then is $f$ bounded?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be analytic in $D_r(z_0)$\ {$z_0$} such that $\Re (f(z))>0$ and let $g(z)=e^{-f(z)}$ be bounded. Then can it be shown that $f$ is bounded? Clearly $g$ is analytic in $D_r(z_0)$ by Riemann's theorem. How can it be shown that $f$ is bounded in the punctutred disk? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First  notice  that the boundedness   hypothesis on  $g$ is redundant since $f=u+iv$ with $u\gt 0$ implies $|e^{-g}|=|e^{-u-iv}|=e^{-u}\lt 1$.
But then it is clear that $f$ needn't be bounded: just consider any isomorphism $f: D_r(z_0)\to U$ (where $U$ is the open right half of $\mathbb C$ defined by $\Re(w)\gt 0$), for example $f(z)=\frac{r-z_0+z}{r+z_0-z}$ .